# How to parameterize code for adding layers in ggplot2

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

We know that `ggplot2` includes a special `+` method for ggplot objects, which uses to add layers to plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- structure(list(Percent = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
               Test = c(4, 2, 3, 5, 2),
               Train = c(10, 12, 10, 13, 15)), 
          .Names = c("Percent", "Test", "Train"), 
          row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Percent)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Test), colour = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Test), colour = "red")
```

Out:

[image]

I turned the above plotting program into a function `plot_func`, but I hope we could control whether I need to add scatter via a parameter, not by commenting out this line: `geom_point(aes(y = Test ), colour = "red") +`.

```
plot_func <- function(data){
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Percent)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = Test), colour = "red") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Test), colour = "red")
  return(print(p))
}

plot_func(df)
```

The expected result would be something like this. Suppose we have a parameter `add_point` in our function `plot_func`, and we set `add_point=FALSE`, it will achieve a plot similar to that after commenting out `geom_point(aes(y = Test), colour = "red") +` .

How to achieve this? Thanks.

```
plot_func <- function(data, add_point=FALSE){
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Percent)) + 
    # geom_point(aes(y = Test), colour = "red") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Test), colour = "red")
  return(print(p))
}

plot_func(df)
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: Use an `if` statement to conditionally add the `geom_point` to `p` if required. Also, imho, it would be better if the function returned `p` rathe4 than `print(p)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as reference: While the approach by @TarJae works it's quite verbose and duplicates all the non-conditional code. Especially when one adds more options this becomes cumbersome and results in code which is harder to maintain.

Instead you could create a conditional layer using:

```
layer_point <- if (add.point) geom_point(aes(y = Test), colour = "red")
```

which could then be added to the plotting code line any other layer. Note that there is no need for an `else` branch. If `add.point=FALSE` `layer_point` will be assigned `NULL`.

For this and some more tricks and best practices for programming with `ggplot2` I would suggest to have a look at the [ggplot2 book](https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html#single-components).

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_func <- function(data, add.point = TRUE) {
  layer_point <- if (add.point) geom_point(aes(y = Test), colour = "red")
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x = Percent)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Test), colour = "red") +
    layer_point
}

plot_func(df, TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
plot_func(df, FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this method is more concise and avoids code duplication. Thanks @TarJae's kind help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As @Limey suggests in his comments, here is how we could do it:

**with if ... else**:

```
plot_func <- function(data, add_point) {
  
  if (add_point == TRUE) {
    p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Percent)) + 
      geom_point(aes(y = Test), colour = "red") + 
      geom_line(aes(y = Test), colour = "red")
    return(p1)
    }
  else  {
    p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Percent)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Test), colour = "red")
    return(p2)
    }
  }
```

**or if ... if**

```
plot_func <- function(data, add_point) {
  
  if (add_point == TRUE) {
    p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Percent)) + 
      geom_point(aes(y = Test), colour = "red") + 
      geom_line(aes(y = Test), colour = "red")
    return(p1)
    }
  if (add_point == FALSE) {
    p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Percent)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Test), colour = "red")
    return(p2)
    }
  }
```

```
plot_func(df, FALSE)
```

[image]

```
plot_func(df, TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: You could also write `if (add_point) ...` or maybe `if (isTRUE(add_point)) ...`